# C# why App.config is copied to my debug and release folder after build?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using `Visual Studio 2008` professional, C#. I found the `App.config` file is copied into the bin\debug and bin\release folder. Is that by default? I thought the `XXX.exe.config` file will be the only configuration file for a project.

1. Is it safe to release our applicaion without the `App.config`?
2. if yes, how to ask VS2008 to stop copy that file after build?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since .Net will be looking for a config file named after your executable, it is safe to release the application without "App.Config".

To stop VS copying the config file into your bin directory, select App.config in the solution explorer, show the Properties for the file, then change the "Copy to Output Directory" option to "Do not copy".

Comment: Beat me to it. I was just double checking

Comment: Great this ans is still valid for Ms Visual Studio 2017 :)